# How to use qicharts2 and ggplots2 together?

Tags: r, ggplot2

according to the package [page](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/qicharts2/index.html), *A qic object Inherits from 'ggplot'*. It is also mentioned that the package *imports: ggplot2 (≥ 2.2.0)*.

This suggests there must be a way to combine ggplot2 and qichart2. I have already tried ggplot(data) + qic(details) with no success.

The reason I want to be able to do this is to improve the formatting of the qicharts2 plots. Googling did not result in anything useful for this (i suspect this is the case due qicharts2 only being released this month (February 2018).

Cheers,

Aaron

Edit: this has been solved.  The solution is qic returns a ggplot object. Meaning you can do qic() + theme() + etc. As mentioned below too.

Follow up, any way to edit/change the gray square?

Edit2: the gray square is hard coded and so are the limits. However, it is possible to retrieve the results from qic()$ and build your own graph.

Edit3: I ended up using qcc package instead. It gave the same results as minitab, qicharts2 gave different ones. See [here](https://github.com/anhoej/qicharts2/issues/5) for more info on this. While I find the design of qcc unpleasant it is readable.

Comment: Have you tried creating a qic object then modifying it as if it were a ggplot object? i.e. ```qic(y) + theme(...)```

Comment: @JackBrookes I have now. And it works. :)

Comment: @JackBrookes do you know how to change the gray background?

Comment: Does `qic(y) + theme_bw() + theme(...) ` work?

Comment: @Djork unfortunately not

Comment: It would be useful if you provided a reproducible example, can you post an a sample of your dataset, e.g. using `dput`

Comment: Your best bet is to look into the `qic` code and see how they produce the grey background.

Comment: Are you sure the gray you are talking about is not the `3-sigma limits` and not the background? See https://anhoej.github.io/qicharts2/articles/qicharts2.html

Comment: @ after talking with the creator, the grey box (from the 3-sigma limits) is hard coded.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

using chart example from the qicharts2 package help

```
library(qicharts2)
library(ggplot2)


p <- qic(age,
    data    = tail(cabg, 100), 
    chart   = 'i',
    exclude = c(45, 70),
    title   = 'Age of the last 100 patients (I chart)',
    ylab    = 'Years',
    xlab    = 'Patient #')

p2 <- p$data


ichart <- ggplot(p2,aes(x,y)) +
  geom_ribbon(ymin = p2$lcl,ymax = p2$ucl, fill = "green",alpha = 0.4) +
  geom_line(colour = "blue", size = .75) + 
  geom_line(aes(x,cl)) +
  geom_point(colour = "black" , fill = "black", size = 1.5) +
  ggtitle(label = "example i chart") +
  labs(x = NULL,
       y = NULL)+
  theme_minimal()

ichart
```

[image]

Now with stepped limits, again with data from the package

```
 step <- qic(month, n,
               data  = cdi,
               chart = 'c',
               part  = 24,
               title = '',
               ylab  = 'Count',
               xlab  = 'Month')

stepped <- step$data

stepped %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x,y)) +
    geom_ribbon(ymin = stepped$lcl,ymax = stepped$ucl, 
    fill = "steel  blue",alpha = 0.4) +
  geom_line(size = .75) + 
  geom_line(aes(x,cl)) +
  geom_point(size = 1.5) +
  ggtitle(label = "example c chart with stepped limits") +
      labs(x = NULL,
       y = NULL) +
  geom_text(aes(label = round(cl.lab,2), y = cl + 1)) +
  theme_minimal() +
  theme(panel.grid.minor = element_blank(),
    panel.grid.major = element_blank()) 

# last line optional
```

[image]